# Node.js Socket.IO Chat Application Cluster Server

Tags: node.js

Actually i have try to create chat application using socket.io
For single server it is working fine. but when i am try to create using cluster server
not working for me it error like
**client not handshaken client should reconnect, socket.io in cluster**
**web socket invalid**

those error are continuously giving in console

Can someone help me to proceed for cluster server for socket.IO

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var sio = require('socket.io');
var server;

 if (cluster.isMaster) {


 for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
     cluster.fork();
 }

 cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
   console.log('A worker with #' + worker.id);
 });

 cluster.on('listening', function(worker, address) {
  console.log('A worker is now connected to ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
 });


  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
  console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
   });
 }
else {
  server =  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);

 _socketServer();
}

var _socketServer = function() {
 io = sio.listen(server);
 io.set("log level", 1);

  io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
 });
 });
```

I am getting error like this

**client not handshaken client should reconnect, socket.io in cluster**

Advance thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when you use Socket.io with the Cluster module - It occurs when a client socket is forwarded to a different worker than the one it started the handshake with - What that means is that one worker handles the first half of the handshake and a different worker handles the second half (so in effect, neither worker handles the full handshake - So the handshake is invalid). You should use the sticky-session module to fix this issue: https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session

Alternatively, if you want a solution that just runs on multiple cores out of the box, you could try SocketCluster: http://socketcluster.io/ - Disclaimer: I'm the main author. Here's the GitHub page: https://github.com/topcloud/socketcluster